# load ajax content in two different div on the same page at the same way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twig

Working with Twig and php, I have three main div in my html page:

```
<select class="form-control" id="choice" name="form[choice]">
  <option value="" disabled selected>make a choice</option>
  <!-- here the path variable matches with an url -->
  <option value="{{ path('get_data_by_choice', {'slug': variable.slug}) }}">
    {{ variable.name }} 
  </option>
</select>

<div id="showOption"></div>

<div id="showCategory">
```

By a jQuery script I return a page content in a div (here in `<div id="showOption"></div`)

Look at the script:

```
<script>
  $('#choice').change(function() {
      var url = $(this).val();
      $.get(url , {} , function(showAvailableConfig) {
          $("#showOption").html(showAvailableConfig));
      })
  });
</script>
```

So it returns me all content of the page with url matches with the variable `{{ path('get_data_by_choice', {'slug': variable.slug}) }}` in the div with `id="ShowOption"`.

This is the content of the page I load via the script:

```
<div id="content1"> some content1 here </div>

<div id="content2"> some other content2 here </div>
```

In fact, with the same script, I would like to append, populate the `div id="showOption"` **with** the `div id="content1"` **and** the `div id="showCategory"` **with** the `div id="content2"`by selecting one value in my initial select tag.

How can I proceed ?

Comment: If I understand, what you want is populate two divs depending on the choice made on two `select` tags? each `select` tag corresponding a `div`?

Comment: @MarkE I want to populate two div on the choice made by one select.

Comment: Oh I think I got it, the ajax call returns the two `div`s in the same call so you want to divide them to put them in different places, is that it?

Comment: @MarkE that's exactly what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a jQuery object with the new data so you can filter the `div`s and then append them.

```
<script>
  $('#choice').change(function() {
      var url = $(this).val();
      $.get(url , {} , function(showAvailableConfig) {
          var newContent = $(showAvailableConfig);
          $("#showOption").html( newContent.filter("#content1") );
          $("#showCategory").html( newContent.filter("#content2") ));
      })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: it almost that, but with this script only the `#showCategory` is populated with the `#content2`, nothing is displayed for the div `#showOption`

Comment: are you sure what the server is returning is complete? try logging the var newContent to the console. There you can fast try the filters and selectors

Comment: sorry my mistake your answer is the good one. I have a parse error in the page I want to load by trying another solution during you you are trying yours !